# When using SOFLAM, do lock-ons require less time?

Tags: battlefield-3

When someone has the target painted using SOFLAM (or possibly CITV station), does locking on with JAV or Guided Missile require less lock-on time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Battlefield.wikia,](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Guided_Missile) referring to Guided missiles,

> The missile can be countered using IR Smoke, causing it to miss its target. The Guided Missile also has the ability to lock onto laser-designated targets provided by teammates, decreasing lock-on time and increasing damage due to the top-down attack.

The javelin page does not mention it, but from my personal experience, locking onto a designated target does indeed take less time than an undesignated one.